# ICallbackEventHandler and ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, icallbackeventhandler

Does anyone know if viewstate is available when using ICallbackEventHandler?
If not is there any work around to get it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewState is available to be read, but you cannot update it.

You might wanna check this out for idea of a workaround: http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2007/03/23/tweaking-the-icallbackeventhandler-and-viewstate.aspx

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer working, are you able to provide any additional context for this answer?